# Numba type changes when indexing

Tags: python, numba

I'm facing a strange problem. The following code (part of a function)

```
@njit
def treedist(treedists, An, Bn, w, M, Theta):
    print(An)
    print(Bn)
    print(An[1])
    print(Bn[1])
```

prints the following:

```
[(0.0, 1), (1.0, 18.071077087009371), (0.0, 0)]
[(0.0, 1), (1.0, 25.897262991223062), (0.0, 0)]
(1.0, 18)
(1.0, 25)
```

For some reason the float64 of the second element in the tuples get converted to an int64. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to input a list of tuples to this function, `njit` seems like the wrong decorator to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following I believe -- Numba can only handle lists of constant types, so it looks at your list and inspects the first element and sees its of type `(float64, int64)`. You can see this if you look at:

```
treedist.inspect_types()
```

or

```
treedist.inspect_llvm()
```

after running the function. It then makes that assumption about the types going forward. If you change all of the tuples to have consistent type:

```
An = [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 18.071077087009371), (0.0, 0.0)]
```

You won't get the cast to int when you print `An[1]`.

If you have a list of inconsistently typed items, numba is going to fail (unfortunately here, it's doing it silently). See the docs that say that lists must be strictly homogeneous:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.29.0/reference/pysupported.html#list

The fact that it isn't "rejecting" your tuples may be because it isn't properly handling complex objects that don't follow the correct convention.

Comment: Posted issue on numba issue tracker here: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2220

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was indeed the problem (and solution)